# Load-time dynamic link library dispatching

Tags: c++, windows, dll, load-time, cpuid

I'd like my Windows application to be able to reference an extensive set of classes and functions wrapped inside a DLL, but I need to be able to guide the application into choosing the correct version of this DLL before it's loaded. I'm familiar with using dllexport / dllimport and generating import libraries to accomplish load-time dynamic linking, but I cannot seem to find any information on the interwebs with regard to possibly finding some kind of entry point function into the import library itself, so I can, specifically, use CPUID to detect the host CPU configuration, and make a decision to load a paricular DLL based on that information. Even more specifically, I'd like to build 2 versions of a DLL, one that is built with `/ARCH:AVX` and takes full advantage of SSE - AVX instructions, and another that assumes nothing is available newer than SSE2.

One requirement: Either the DLL must be linked at load-time, or there needs to be a super easy way of manually binding the functions referenced from outside the DLL, and there are many, mostly wrapped inside classes.

Bonus question: Since my libraries will be cross-platform, is there an equivalent for Linux based shared objects?

Comment: Use factory pattern to get whatever implementation you want?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I'd look at [delay-loaded DLLs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790.aspx) with a custom [helper function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09t6x5ds.aspx). The helper should be able to determine at run-time which DLL to load.

Comment: An easier alternative: Combine delay-loading with calling [SetDllDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686203.aspx)/[AddDllDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh310513.aspx) during application startup. Not quite as flexible, as all related DLLs must share the same name, and be located in different directories.

Comment: I read up a little bit on delay loading, but it seems apparent that I have to set that as a linker setting in the executable application (true?), which I'd rather not, but maybe it would be ok, since I could document that requirement in its usage.

Comment: You have to enable delay-loading in the module, that's a client of the DLLs. If you have no control over the client, you could create a proxy DLL, with delay-loading enabled, that implements the runtime-dynamic import resolution. That way an application can link against the proxy DLL using regular load-time dynamic linking, and still resolve platform-specific library imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you avoid dynamic resolution of your DLL from your executable if at all possible, since it is just going to make your life hard, especially since you have a lot of exposed interfaces and they are not pure C.

**Possible Workaround**

Create a "chooser" process that presents the necessary UI for deciding which DLL you need, or maybe it can even determine it automatically.  Let that process move whatever DLL has been decided on into the standard location (and name) that your main executable is expecting.  Then have the chooser process launch your main executable; it will pick up its DLL from your standard location without having to know which version of the DLL is there.  No delay loading, no wonkiness, no extra coding; very easy.

If this just isn't an option for you, then here are your starting points for delay loading DLLs.  Its a much rockier road.

**Windows**

- LoadLibrary() to get the DLL in memory: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx
- GetProcAddress() to get pointer to a function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx
- OR possibly special delay-loaded DLL functionality using a custom helper function, although there are limitations and potential behavior changes.. never tried this myself: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790.aspx (suggested by Igor Tandetnik and seems reasonable).

**Linux**

- dlopen() to get the SO in memory: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlopen.html
- dladdr() to get pointer to a function: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dladdr.3.html

Comment: It should be noted that the `possible workaround` will not allow two instances of the app to run at the same time with different DLL choices.

Comment: Good point, although it sounds like OP would make the same decision every time based on the machine config.  Worst case, you could make it work by having chooser exe modify the LD_LIBRARY_PATH (and Windows equivalent) environment variable before launching the main executable, which would point it to a new directory containing the chosen DLL; new directory would be named based on process ID or random ID.

Comment: Potential behavior changes are very, very unlikely. For one, the helper functions for delay-loading are [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09t6x5ds.aspx). And they have changed once only ([Changes in the DLL Delayed Loading Helper Function Since Visual C++ 6.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2b054ds4.aspx)). VC++6 shipped in 1998. The [Constraints of Delay Loading DLLs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx1x886y.aspx) are probably not an issue for the OP.

Comment: OK, so providing a UI is not an option because I will be shipping a runtime SDK for developers, so drop in and link is best. If I go with delay loading, 1) Can I keep my class and function definitions the same without resorting to dropping to function pointers, meaning will my definitions be late-linked? 2) Does specifying the late loaded DLL in the exe linker settings prevent the DLL from being loaded earlier if the import library is statically linked against, or do I need to unload it and reload?

Comment: @Kumputer 1) Yes. 2) No (unless you do something stupid in WinMain or other DllMain's). I really suggest you read the links @​IgorTandetnik posted in his comment.

Comment: I had a few minutes to play around with this a little. Seems it should be easy enough, just a matter of enabling delayed loading from the host application, and using __HrLoadAllImportsForDll after figuring out which dll to pass into it. I think this would be fine actually. I could package headers, libs, and dll's into the SDK, along with a very small amount of sample code or a prepared cpp so the developer can get some extra performance from some machines if they choose, otherwise the lowest common denominator dll will be loaded by default, which is also fine. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

To add to qexyn's answer, one can mimic delay loading on Linux by generating a small static stub library which would `dlopen` on first call to any of it's functions and then forward actual execution to shared library. Generation of such stub library can be automatically generated by custom project-specific script or [Implib.so](https://github.com/yugr/Implib.so):

```
# Generate stub
$ implib-gen.py libxyz.so
# Link it instead of -lxyz
$ gcc myapp.c libxyz.tramp.S libxyz.init.c
```